# Is it possible that $\ker(T) = \operatorname{im}(T)$ for some linear transformation $T:V \to V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Help would be very appreciated.

It it possible that $\ker(T) = \operatorname{im}(T)$ for some linear transformation $T:V \to V$?

Comment: Yes. Consider the trivial function $f(v)=0$.

Comment: @user69810 $\ker f = V \ne \operatorname{im} f = \{0\}$.

Comment: @AymanHourieh You are correct. Take V to be the {0} space and it will work.

Comment: @user69810 It works with $V = \{0\}$ but what's the fun in that? :)

Answer (score 27):

Consider the linear transformation $T : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ so that:
$$
T(x, y) = (y, 0)
$$

We have:
$$
\ker T = \{(x, 0) : x \in \Bbb R\} = \operatorname{im} T
$$

I arrived at this example by noticing that such a linear transformation must have $T^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 12):

Since $ \dim \operatorname{ker} T + \dim \operatorname{im} T = n$, we must have $n=2k$.

Now, take any basis of $V$, say $v_i$

Define $T(v_i) = v_{k+i}$ for $i=1$ to $k$, and $T(v_i) = 0 $ for $i=k+1 $ to $2k$. Extend this out as a linear functional to $V$. Then , $\operatorname{im} V = \operatorname{ker} V$.

Answer (score 8):

It will be possible if $\dim(V)$  is **even** because $\dim(T)+\mathrm{null}(T)=\dim(V)$ so $\dim(V)=2\dim(T)$

And then you will have, for example, $2n$ basis for $V$ as $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n,\alpha_{n+1},\ldots,\alpha_{2n}\}$.

For every $T$ that maps $n$ arbitrary basis elements from $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n,\alpha_{n+1},\ldots,\alpha_{2n}\}$ to zero and maps the others (remains basis ) to the first $n$ basis elements, it will be our answer.

Comment: $\Large{+1}^{\ddot\smile}$.

Comment: Hi. Plz be at the chat room.