# Finding a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\text{ker}(T)=\text{Im}(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

First of all, I know that $\dim(\text{ker}(T)) =\dim(\text{Im}(T))= 1$ and that $T( \text{ker}(T))= T( \text{Im}(T))= 0$.
But now I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Wolgwang Ok but I am pretty sure that you got me

Comment: This time I edited the question for you. Next time, be more careful ;)

Comment: @FrancescoScavella appreciate that

Comment: Does this answer your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529005/give-an-example-of-a-linear-transformation-tr2-rightarrow-r2-such-that-n

Comment: @KishalaySarkar no. this is the opposite way

Comment: See the title of your question

Comment: Another useful thread might be https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393880/is-it-possible-that-kert-operatornameimt-for-some-linear-transformat @FunnyCallsw

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially looking for an endomorphism $T$, such that:

$T \circ T = T^2 = 0$

If we consider the matrix representation of $T$, we can see that what we need is a 2 by 2 matrix that is the zero matrix when raised to the power of $2$. Thus we arrive at the formula:

$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}^2 = \begin{bmatrix}a^2 + bc & b(a+d)\\c(a+d) & d^2+bc\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

From this you can extract the following relations:

$a^2 = -bc = d^2$

$(b = 0 \land c = 0) \lor a = -d $

Assuming $T \neq 0$, we have for $a, c \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$:

$d = -a$

$b = \frac{-a^2}{c}$

That means for any two non-zero $a, c$, you can construct a $T$ with the property you are looking for. That is:

$T = \begin{bmatrix}a & \frac{-a^2}{c}\\c & -a\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: $b = 0 \wedge c = 0 \;\vee\; a = -d$ is ambiguous. I also think you are using $\land$ where you should use $\lor$ and vice versa. (This is easier to get right if you actually use the commands `\lor` and `\land`.)

Comment: Well afaik, $\land$ always binds stronger than $\lor$. Apart from that, the condition for $c(a+d)$ and $b(a+d)$ being both zero is the same as $c = 0 = b$ or $(a+d)=0$. We have: $c(a+d) = 0 \implies c = 0 \lor (a+d) = 0$. Assuming $(a+d) \neq 0$, we can use the equality $b(a+d) = 0$, and arrive at $b = 0$. I'm extremely certain that what I wrote is true. Can you provide a counter-example perhaps?

Comment: You're right that you didn't mix them up. I was wrong there. But I am pretty certain that the vast majority of times I've seen $\land$ and $\lor$ in the same statement, they have been disambiguated with parentheses. People wouldn't do that if they felt there was universal consensus about the order of the two operations.

Comment: Alright then, I am updating my answer accordingly. Thanks for the advice!